# TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType' python error

Tags: python

Both f(x) or fp(x) aren't "NoneType" but however
it's telling me that abs can't operate "NoneType". What seems to be the problem?

```
abs(fp(x))
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Copy the code into the question, rather than using images. It's respectful to the people trying to help, so they don't have to re-type your example. In any case, you should provide a [mcve] instead of a chunk of code we can't run. We don't have `x`, `f`, `fp`, or `eps`.

Comment: Provide some sample input output.

Comment: "I'm really sure that f(x) or fp(x) aren't "NoneType"" - one of the most important lessons you'll need to learn as a programmer is that if the error message says you're wrong about something, you're probably wrong.

Comment: The function `fp()` is clearly returning the value `None`. This is the default return value for python functions, unless you explicitly return some other value, for instance: `def fp(x): return x * 2`. If you want help debugging, you must include the source code for `fp`.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming here that `fp(x)` or `f(x)` are functions that don't **return** anything.

Take a look at this,

```
def fp(x):
    print(x)

print(fp(10))
```

You might think that the output of this would be `10` but you get this,

```
10
None
```

Take a look at this function,

```
def fp():
    pass
print(fp())
```

Output:

```
None
```

Functions by **default** return a **None type**. So in your case when you are doing `abs(fp(x))` the problem seems to be that you are doing `abs()` on `None` that's why you get the error.

**Look at this,**

```
def fp():
        pass
abs(fp())
```

Output:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType' python error
```

So add a return statement to the function and you can see the error will be gone

```
def fp(x):
    return x
some_value = abs(fp(-10.5))
print(some_value)
```

Output:

```
10.5
```

Now the error is gone.